# Delete list with a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can I delete list inside list with list comprehension :

```
delete_canceled = [a_order for a_order in signal_order_position for c_order in signal_order_canceled if
             (a_order[0][0] in c_order[0][0] and a_order[0][1] in c_order[0][1] and a_order[0][4] in c_order[0][4])]
```

without using this:

```
    for delete_can in delete_canceled:
        signal_order_position.remove(delete_can)
        print "removed by canceled"
```

Comment: With list `l`, make a list comprehension that retains elements of `l` if they meet some criteria.  `l = [i for i in l if func(i)]`

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the list comprehension for `delete_canceled` correctly? You might end up with duplicate values of `a_order`. Also the suggestion to look at `itertools.product`.

Comment: @Elmex80s I am sure I used `delete_canceled` correctly.

Comment: As @PatrickHaugh says, do something like this `signal_order_position  = [x for x in signal_order_position if x not in delete_canceled]`. Be careful for double entries.

Comment: @Elmex80s would try. thank you.